# howto create issue comment in Gemini 5 API

Tags: gemini

I'm trying to add a comment to issue using [Gemini 5 c# API](http://docs.countersoft.com/item-comment-endpoint/).

The problem is that GeminiService.Item.IssueCommentCreate returns null.

commentDto object is created and passed to the IssueCommentCreate with the same properties filled (Comment, IssueId, Visibility) as for previous gemini api (FullName and ProjectId are not filled). I've tried to fill ProjectId but no luck.

Could you please share how are you adding comments?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that I've specified comment visibility that is not in the comment visibility classifier in the database.

For 15 visibility value null is returned by IssueCommentCreate but comments with visibility 1 and 12 are added without any problem

In the previous Gemini version (API Version 4.0.1.3038) I am able to add a comment with visibility 414 without any problem (comment object instance with ID filled is returned for it)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

We used Gemini's sample API for ours and it works:

```
var comments = new IssueComment();

            comments.Comment = txtComment.Text;
            comments.ProjectId = projectId;
            comments.UserId = userId;
            comments.IssueId = issueId;

            login.Item.IssueCommentCreate(comments);
```

Comment: seems that problem is that I don't have some kind of permission on the Gemini site. Because when I've got administrator permission my code started to work

Comment: it is a little bit strange that null is returned by IssueCommentCreate because when I'm trying to get project versions exception Forbidden is raised. Code is `geminiService.Projects.GetVersions(issue.Issue.ProjectId)` . And Gemini permissions is the same when I'm adding an issue comment and triyng to get a version

Comment: Works ok for me with non admin user and comment.